# How to convert JSON string to C# IEnumerable<JToken>

Tags: c#, json, json.net, token, ienumerable

so i'm getting a json file from the web into my program that reads something like this:

```json
{
  "10": {
    "appid": 10,
    "name": "Counter-Strike",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "publisher": "Valve",
    "score_rank": "",
    "positive": 183964,
    "negative": 4782,
    "userscore": 0,
    "owners": "10,000,000 .. 20,000,000",
    "average_forever": 11228,
    "average_2weeks": 289,
    "median_forever": 210,
    "median_2weeks": 114,
    "price": "999",
    "initialprice": "999",
    "discount": "0",
    "ccu": 13567
  },
  "20": {
    "appid": 20,
    "name": "Team Fortress Classic",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "publisher": "Valve",
    "score_rank": "",
    "positive": 5223,
    "negative": 871,
    "userscore": 0,
    "owners": "2,000,000 .. 5,000,000",
    "average_forever": 522,
    "average_2weeks": 0,
    "median_forever": 20,
    "median_2weeks": 0,
    "price": "499",
    "initialprice": "499",
    "discount": "0",
    "ccu": 93
  },
  "30": {
    "appid": 30,
    "name": "Day of Defeat",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "publisher": "Valve",
    "score_rank": "",
    "positive": 4866,
    "negative": 543,
    "userscore": 0,
    "owners": "5,000,000 .. 10,000,000",
    "average_forever": 2191,
    "average_2weeks": 343,
    "median_forever": 24,
    "median_2weeks": 343,
    "price": "499",
    "initialprice": "499",
    "discount": "0",
    "ccu": 130
  },
  "40": {
    "appid": 40,
    "name": "Deathmatch Classic",
    "developer": "Valve",
    "publisher": "Valve",
    "score_rank": "",
    "positive": 1789,
    "negative": 400,
    "userscore": 0,
    "owners": "5,000,000 .. 10,000,000",
    "average_forever": 297,
    "average_2weeks": 0,
    "median_forever": 8,
    "median_2weeks": 0,
    "price": "499",
    "initialprice": "499",
    "discount": "0",
    "ccu": 6
  }
```

I'm importing it has a string how can I get an enumerable or list where I get all the tokens as (Jtokens) so "`IEnumerable<JToken> or List<JToken>`" like ["10", "40", "60"...]

This is what my code looks like right now:

```cs
string json = webClient.DownloadString("https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/");

tokens = JObject.Parse(json).Children();
//token = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("applist.apps");

for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count(); i++)
{
    int currentID = (int)tokens.ElementAt(i).SelectToken("appid");

    if (SteamApps.BIsSubscribedApp(new AppId_t((uint)currentID)))
    {
        threads.Add(new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(AddToDictionary)));
        threads.Last().Start(new stats(i, currentID, threads.Last()));
    }
}
```

But this isn't working at all and I can't read any values..

Comment: Please explain why you need `JToken` here, and not just desieralize this normally

Comment: I just need to me able to do something like `tokens.ElementAt(i).SelectToken("appid")`
My thinking is i can have a List or something of JTokens and then I can go through the list and get all the appID from each one.

Comment: So you are just after a list of AppID ?

Comment: Kind of, from that JSON I just need all AppIDs and the Name of that appid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are oodles of ways to do this and variations. However, this is simple enough. The premise is *Parse* -> *Select First* -> *Target property by name*

```
var results = JToken.Parse(input)
   // Select past the dictionary
   .Select(x => x.First()) 
   // project property values in to a value tuple
   .Select(x => (Appid: x["appid"], Name: x["name"]))
   .ToArray();

foreach (var item in results)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
(10, Counter-Strike)
(20, Team Fortress Classic)
(30, Day of Defeat)
(40, Deathmatch Classic)
```

Answer (score 0):

by selecting the token u want from the list of objects that was deserialised from the json string using system.linq

newlist = deserList.Select(x => x.Jtoken);

Comment: Hm, sorry i'm pretty dumb with json this is the first time using it, how do I deserialize the string to get a list of objects?